# Do I need an ADFS and Proxy?

Tags: adfs, single-sign-on

The client has an ADFS server and they use our APP hosted on IIS developed on Dot Net.
How Do I set UP ADFS - do I need ADFS Proxy server as well, Can I use an existing AD server and install ADFS, we should also create an URL for access. something like adfs.domain.com
[image]